# How to stop ExecuteSqlInterpolated from wrapping string params with single quotes?

Tags: c#, postgresql, .net-core, npgsql, ef-core-3.0

I have a call in EF Core 3 to ProgresSQL server that has multiple string parameters. One of them is a string which is a concatenation of strings already wrapped with single quotes like this:

```
var listOfParams = "'a',','b','c'";
```

and later passed to a query which looks like this:

```
var id = "Customer1";
DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(
   "SELECT ""CustomerNumber"" FROM dbo.""Customer"" 
      WHERE ""Id"" = {id} AND ""CustomerNumber"" IN ({listOfParams})");
```

The problem is that while wrapping id with quotes is correct, for the second parameter which has quotes already a second wrapping occurs of some sort or possibly escaping of single quotes and this is what I would like to avoid.
Yet, I can't find any relatively simple way. Perfectly if it is possible to keep listOfParams as an SQL param, otherwise caching of query plan would be impossible. Passing a list directly doesn't seem to work either. Looks like EF Core doesn't support it.

Thanks, Radek

Comment: It's absolutely not ocrrect to wrap it in quotes, and that's not what `ExecuteSqlInterpolated` does. It finds the interpolation and changes it to a named parameter, which means you end up with `""CustomerNumber"" IN (@listOfParams)` which is the same as `""CustomerNumber"" = @listOfParams` and the parameter is just a string which happens to have commas in it, it will never be interpreted as a list. You need to use JSON parameter, or a `STRING_SPLIT` or similar on your variable

Comment: @Charlieface: Actually your answer gave me an idea. I could slightly modify the query to include this: select unnest(string_to_array({listOfParams}, ',')) as "CustomerNumber" and then use the result of this select in all queries I have. Actually I already checked it and it seems to be working. Thanks :)

Comment: Indeed that is one method, but you need to remove the quotes and do it like this `""CustomerNumber"" IN (select * from unnest(string_to_array({listOfParams}, ',')))`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried just using a LINQ approach?

```
var listOfParams =  "a b c".Split();
var r = DBContext.Customer
  .Where(c => c.Id == id && listOfParams.Contains(c.CustomerNumber))
  .Select(c => c.CustomerNumber);
```

In SQLServer .Contains is mapped to IN - PG may well be the same

Comment: Well the actual query is quite complex and prevents the usage of Linq unfortunately.

Comment: You should post up the actual query, so we can offer help with it - no point posting a dumbed down question if you can't then reverse convert any dumbed-down answers back into the complex variant. It's possible to mix n match complex SQL with LINQ these days

Comment: I get your point. Let me try one solution somehow suggested by Charlieface and if I am stuck again I will provide the full query (a bit obfuscated of course).

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is to parameterize your list (`a, b, c`), then you probably want to pass an array parameter - this should be fully supported by Npgsql and the EF Core provider, and properly reuse query plans/prepared statements.

Note that for arrays, you need to use PG's `= ANY (<array>)` construct rather than `IN`.

```cs
var id = "Customer1";
var listOfParams = new[] { "a", "b", "c" };

DbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlInterpolated(
   "SELECT ""CustomerNumber"" FROM dbo.""Customer"" 
      WHERE ""Id"" = {id} AND ""CustomerNumber"" = ANY ({listOfParams})");
```